# Angular: How to build files which are the same as the files ng serve creates

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I'm optimizing my Angular application and using webpack-bundle-analyzer to inspect the size of bundles. When I run `ng build --stats-json` it creates bundle.js files and creates a json file which webpack-bundle-analyzer parses. This works as expected, but is there a way to build angular application without optimizations which ng build performs, i.e. get the files which are the same files `ng serve` produces. I want this because my application is really big and it takes like 15 seconds to reload it while developing. So I would like to be able to inspect these files as well.

Comment: `ng build` does a dev build by default, no optimizations. `ng build --prod` does a production build with all the optimizations.

Comment: it still does some optimization. in my project size of `vendor.bundle.js` is 6.75 MB when using ng build and 18.3 MB when using ng serve.

Comment: You can play around with various [build flags](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build). Try something like this: `ng b --aot=false --build-optimizer=false --optimization=false`. There may be some trial and error with this.

Comment: Why cant use the source tab > and select webpack and choose your file to inspect which is taking time when serving your angular application. Also you can use the network tab to see clearly which one is taking time.?

Comment: did you tried `ng build --output-hashing=none` it will not build same as `serve` rather than it will generate `scripts.js, runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js`.

Comment: @RagavanRajan I know how to see file size, but I want to know size of each library inside bundles during development.

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed it still generates the same files as `ng build`

Comment: if you refactor your modules to lazy-loading, it will ease the reload a bit. I've worked on an app and reduced it from 50seconds load time to 2 just by adding lazy loading (and some other refactoring)

Comment: From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build, "All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking". So I don't think you can get exactly the same files. But as commented by @RagavanRajan you can alway see and analyse the files produced by `ng serve` in your browser's debugger

Comment: If your statement **"I want to know size of each library inside bundles during development"** is true then all you need to do is use [source-map-explorer](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer/blob/master/README.md) as described in the official Angular docs on [taking Angular to production](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't, because `ng serve` works in memory and does not write to disk.

As a workaround you can use your browser's debugger or  visit your dev server under the /webpack-dev-server path (i.e. if you're running angular on port 4200, go to http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to optimize your application would be using the combination of lazyloading modules with libraries. That would really split your application in separate artifacts reducing your load time.

See here about the libraries: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library

Answer (score 0):

I always use this command line to get the *raw* files, without optimizations (but with a shorter build time):

```
ng build --stats-json --source-map=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Consider adding it to your package.json in the `scripts` section.

See the full list of command line options in [the official angular cli build documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options).

---

AOT is default for `prod`, but not for `serve` and `build`. So you should not have to turn it off manually, usually:

> JIT compilation is the default when you run the build-only or the build-and-serve-locally CLI commands
>
> [...]
>
> The --prod meta-flag compiles with AOT by default.

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: This will not produce the same files as `serve` does